# Unable to trace the source of a stack overflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a Java application that is working as a service. After several days running I get a stack overflow error. The problem is that the stack frame in my source where the error is being originated is not in the error reported by printStackTrace function. I have no idea about how to find where the problem is.

This is the result of printStackTrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(LinkedList.java:684)
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:700)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:699)
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:700)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:699)
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:700)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:699)
        ... (this is repeated hundreds of times)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:699)
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:700)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:699)
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:700)
```

Comment: Does this happen consistently? You could connect to it with a profiler and find code hotspots. Or better yet, set up an agent to do a thread dump on an error. I know this can be done automatically on OutOfMemory errors, not sure about other types. But it's worth looking into.

Comment: Some recursive algorithms like recursive blob detection benefit from an increased stack size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced as follows:

```
List<String> l = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < 2800; i++) {
    l = l.subList(...);
}
l.listIterator(...);
```

So, pay attention on all invocations of `subList()` and make sure they don't form a long chain of sublists as above.

Such a chain is a recursive structure (each sublist keeps a reference to its parent list), and calling `listIterator()` on a very long chain causes a very deep recursion which causes stack overflow.

Comment: Yep, that's what it looked like to me as well. If possible, try to get a sublist from the *original* list, if you need this.

Comment: Also: it's interesting that `SubList.subList()` does **not** produce a sublist based on the *original* `List`. That would be a good optimization, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes this is possibly the cause. I was using subList to rotate a performance log: I first removed entries by using subList and then I added new entries to the end. This was repeated thousands of times so... however the question remains unanswered: how to find the point in my source if it is buried deeply in the stack and printStackTrace cannot reach it... may be I should give a try to @G_H comment.

Answer (score 1):

Look for uses of the `List.subList()` method - that's the only place where you can get an instance of `java.util.SubList` (a class with package visibility).

You could also try upading to a newer Java version - your stack trace doesn't match the structure of the list classes in current versions, so your problem may not occur (or result in a differen error that's easier to diagnose) on a more current version.